# Interactive sort for only top elements

Tags: algorithms, ordering

I have a set of objects and a set of comparison results for some of them.

I want an algorithm that returns the next comparison I should make to two objects towards having a way to know the full order of all objects. If the order of all objects can be already known I should get the objects ordered.

Requirements: ask for the minimal number of comparisons between objects as they are the most expensive operation.

For example: I know elements A,B,C,D and relations A->B , A->C , B->D , C->D the algorithm should return next pair to compare B and C

Comment: Unfortunately no efficient algorithms are known for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been considered in the literature: given a poset $P$ and a list of elements whose order is consistent with $P$, how many comparisons are needed in order to order the list? If there are $e(P)$ many extensions of $P$ to a linear order, then clearly at least $\log_2 e(P)$ many comparisons are needed. Conversely, Kislytsin and Fredman showed (separately) that $\log_2 e(P) + 2n$ comparisons suffice, but their algorithms cannot be implemented efficiently. Kahn and Kim gave in their classic paper [Entropy and Sorting](https://cs.haifa.ac.il/%7Eilan/concrete_complexity/reading_material/khan_kim.pdf) an efficient algorithm which uses $O(\log e(P))$ comparisons.

While these results might have been improved along the years (you can check this by going over papers citing Kahn–Kim), it might be too much to ask for an *optimal* algorithm which can be implemented efficiently.